# How do i find the sequence of digit in a long string which is numbers only p5 js

Tags: string, numbers, digit, p5.js

I have this problem. How can i write code that would search for a sequence of digits in a string that is numbers only. For instance for this string
`123124567`
i want to search for n-digit sequence and if it repeats one or more time show it.

I'll show it on example of what i want to achive
For `123124567`
Show all 2-digit sequences (that are in a row) so output should be
`12 23 31 12 24 45 56 67`
And from it show those that repeat one or more time in this case
`12`

Im r begginger but i would like to teach myself to to this as i am working on bigger project where i need to show every number sequences in very long string.
I tried to use the  Regular Expressions for it but then i got the results like: `12 31 24 56` and it wasnt checking every possible two digits sequence like `12 23 31 12 24 45 56 67`

```
var textfield;
var output;
var submit;

function setup() {
  noCanvas();
  textfield = select("#input");
  output = select('#output');
  submit = select("#submit");
  submit.mousePressed(newText);
}

function newText() {
  var s = textfield.value();

  var r = /\d\d/g; //here i would need to adjust it so to given digit length
  var matches = s.match(r);

  for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    createP(matches[i]);
   //at this point the results are wrong not showing all possible sequences
  }

  }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you really want to use a regular expression, then I'd recommend googling "regular expression find repeated substrings" for a ton of results.

Or you could simplify your approach and do the matching yourself. Break the problem down into smaller sub-steps: first write code that splits your `String` up. Then add each two-digit number into a data structure and check for repeats as you add them.

Comment: Well im pretty sure i wanna get rid of regular expression.

Comment: Though my problem is how to split my spring in to the digit that repeat. 
Problem is getting bigger when i don't want to search for two-digit numbers, but for 50-digit numbers

Comment: @ElKolorado Can't you just use the `substring()` function?

Comment: I could have problem with specifing the "n-digit", cause 155 is already huge number and probably there are higher digit numbers than that, so also im not sure yet how i want to present the output, cause what i am aiming for is to kinda split the string into the most probably output. What i mean is that this string is a cipher in a game, which im trying to decipher, but first step would be to recognise the same digit patterns and split(color) the string so u can see the similarities in it. So im not sure how i want to "bite" this

Comment: I cant, cause my string is 11120 digits long. http://pastebin.com/Da7b6kCR My goal on this string is to find as many digit sequences as possible. Starting from 2-digit ending up to like 155-digit or more, cause if u ctrl+f "27585765197278894388721512889521961800311457278572611857642197096805796366125275705845217652197278304648765159564611414519889975112161518005953724348562510" u will see it repeats. It is really hard to do it manually at i wanted to write program that would do it for me, thats why i started to learn programming.

Comment: Why does the length of your String prevent you from using the `substring()` function? Have you tried that at all, or are you just assuming it won't work for some reason?

Comment: It will work but how do i know whats the indexs location of the digit sequence im looking for, when i don't know yet how to search for for example all 5-digit sequences that repeat?

Comment: Can't you just store the index for each sequence? Or go through each index, find the 5-digit sequence that starts at that index, and compare it to all of the sequences you've seen before?

Comment: Think about how you'd do this by hand, with a piece of paper and a pencil. You'd probably write down the indexes and the sequences at that index, and then for each new index you'd check whether you've seen that sequence at any previous indexes. Do that with a data structure that keeps track of the sequences at each index. A basic array of strings would probably do the job. Then after you get that working, you might think about improving performance by maybe going the other way, mapping sequences to indexes via a hash or something. Then lookup time would be improved.

Comment: I decided to make it with substring as u recommended. Though for start i just assumed that n-digits will be 2 digits.

Comment: this is what i got now, im stuck with problem how to show the same digit numbers now.

'function setup(){

var str1 = "12341256"
var n = 2;
var a = 0;
var b = n;
while (a <= str1.length & b < str1.length+1) {
  res = str1.substring(b, a);
  a = a + 1
  b = b + 1
  createP(res);
}
}'
so output is 12 23 34 41 12 25 56
How do i search for any duplicates?

Comment: sorry i can't edit the posts yet xD
`function setup(){

var str1 = "12341256"
var n = 2;
var a = 0;
var b = n;
while (a <= str1.length & b < str1.length+1) {
  res = str1.substring(b, a);
  a = a + 1
  b = b + 1
  createP(res);
}
}`

Comment: Like I said, you need a data structure to store the sequences you've seen so far. An array would do the trick, going from index to sequence. Or you could get fancier and go from sequence to index.

Comment: I don't have clue how to do it. When i added `spl = split(res, ",");` to my code i can see in my console that arrays that are made in the while loop all are the same its always array[1], and when i try to save it to .txt only one sequence shows up. 
How i can store the each sequence in my while loop that i see in my console log, and store it to like .txt file?. Cause only createP seems to give all results

Comment: Why would you split on a comma? Why are you using the split function at all? You need to use the `substring()` function.

Comment: i used `substring()` already to find all 2-digit, but its in while loop, and i don't know how i am able to store it.

Comment: Take a step back. Create the data structure first. Can you create a data structure that contains each sequence? Separately, can you create a function that detects duplicates in a data structure? When you get each working, then you can start thinking about combining them into a single program.

Comment: Hmm. I don't know how to create such data structure :(
I know that then i could test it on function that would detect the duplicates.

All what i know is that i can see my sequences in console.log, but i don't have clue how to make data structure from it

Comment: Like I said, either an array or a map would work. I would start with an array because it's easier to think about, but that's just me. The point is you need to try something. Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions, and it's not designed for extended back-and-forth conversations like this. Try something out and post a [mcve] along with a specific question if you get stuck again. Good luck.